# Silverlight Login page work on machine but not on other machine (window 7)

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0, wcf-security

I face some strange issue in Silverlight 5 on machine which use window 7.

I have a Silverlight app and after deploying it, it works fine on all user machine but on some of user machine it does not working.

For Example My Username : Test and password is Test.

Now when I use this info to login my app on my machine and also some of other machine then it works fine but when I use same info on other machine (Window 7) it does not work.

I have set mesg for invalid login info in wcf service and return mesg to user. I found that when I use invalid logininfo then it display mesg which I set in wcf method.

I also uninstall old Silverlight and install new on window 7 machine but then also not working.

I think there are something which block to response of wcf service. I am stuck into this issue.

Thanks,
Hitesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the similar issue once

When you are talking about the WCF service not working on some machines,
the first thing I would check is the time on that machine(some users set their own time, which is different from the standard time in that particular time zone, WCF service just does not accept the requests from these machines) and then the security level of the WCF service and on the User machine.

Hope this info helps..

Comment: You are right. I found same solution on my own. Thanks.